# Почему js-файл ругается на jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пользуюсь WebStorm'ом. В нем создал Bootstrap-проект TestingSourse. В нем папку TestingSourse.

Вот проект:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('hello world');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="adminpage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

но js-файл ругается

Трассировка:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
C:\Users\%Пользователь%\WebstormProjects\TestingSourse\AdminPage\js\adminpage.js
C:\Users\%Пользователь%\WebstormProjects\TestingSourse\AdminPage\js\adminpage.js:1
$(document).ready(function(){
^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\%Пользователь%\WebstormProjects\TestingSourse\AdminPage\js\adminpage.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

jquery установлен в node_modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вначале надо подключить `jquery.min.js`, а потом только `adminpage.js`

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш комментарий очень помог!